# add local repository to remote repository

Tags: git

I have a copy of remote repository in my machine. It might have been changed. I just want to connect my local repository to the remote repo, but I want the local to be sync with remote and all the change in the local be discarded and the local be a copy of remote. I don't want any change from my machine to be pushed to the remote.it has multiple branches.

I transfer the repo from another machine by USB (I didn't clone repo from remote) because it was large (about 2GB) and I want to setup the git for this and connect it to remote.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can't you just delete your local copy and clone the original remote repo again?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I can't clone it because the project volume is 2GB and my internet is limited

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Follow these steps:

1. Create a new folder
2. Run the command `git init` inside this folder
3. Run the command `git remote add origin <your-repository-url>`
4. Run the command `git pull`
5. You may need to set up SSH locally, depending on it you are using SSH, if you use HTTPS, then this isn't necessary as it does use keys.
6. Your new local folder will be exactly the same as your remote folder
7. Confirm that this is the case; if so then delete the old local folder that you don't want anymore

Comment: I have copied the repo in a folder (e.g. my_ptoject) . I run those command but git still show the files unstaged. and every time I run a command it ask for user name and pass. and doesn't track my file for change

Comment: Ok, run `git add . `, then `git commit -a` and type your commit message. 

Also it's asking for your username because you need to set up your SSH keys. This will authenticate you using keys instead of a username/password.